# Trying to recover an old Sourcesafe ssa archive

Tags: version-control, visual-sourcesafe, visual-sourcesafe-2005

So I've got an old sourcesafe archive file (extension ssa) that I created from an old sourcesafe archive way back in 2004.  I'd like to get a few files out of there.  I'm totally not interested in actually using sourcesafe, or for that matter recovering any of the history.  I just want the latest version of some of the files.

So, I've tried searching the Microsoft site to see if there's a tool that does it.  No luck.  Tried searching for a copy of Sourcesafe that I could actually purchase (I'm not looking to pirate here.  I've got funding to get this to work).  Microsoft doesn't sell it anymore.  Tried torrenting it.  No one is sharing.  Tried google searches to see if anyone has a tool that will read ssa files.  Nope.

Sort of at a standstill here and looking for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Some versions of SourceSafe were bundled with Visual Studio. Visual Studio 98 came with SourceSafe 6, for example. So it might be worth looking for a copy of Visual Studio from the time frame you're interested in.